# Nested forms with Vaadin / display contents of a collection

Tags: java, nested-forms, vaadin

I would like to display a complex Java Bean in a Vaadin form so that the user can edit the bean. However the bean consists of simple properties (String, Integer and so on), but also of a collection of yet another bean (though this has only simple properties).

What I like to do know is to display a table which contains the simple properties of the nested bean in its columns. Each row displays one instance of the nested bean. Of course there has to be a way to add new rows (append to the collection) and remove rows (remove from the collection).

I've done some research how this can be achived with Vaadin. However, to no success. Is there a kind of pattern which solves this problem? What steps have to be taken?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this example on Nested Beans and Subforms will help:

[Book of Vaadin Examples](http://demo.vaadin.com/book-examples/book/?restartApplication#component.form.subform.boundselect)

Also, this example looks like what you need http://demo.vaadin.com/book-examples/book/?restartApplication#component.form.subform.nestedtable